# format a number keeping its sign in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

Is there a way to format in PHP a number always keeping its sign (+ or -)?

In .NET this will be something like:

```
string myString = number.ToString("+#;#");
```

Comment: That .NET version won't work as you intend.

Comment: @Mark: you mean it should be just "+#"? I saw it somewhere in a forum, not tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$myString = sprintf("%+f", number);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
   $myString = sprintf("%+d", 25);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%+d", $number)
```